# Hide/Show elements when an event is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to manage triggered events on buttons but I can't get the exact result. By default, the `div id="mailArea"` is displayed but when I click on web button, I would like that this div is hidden and vice-versa.
    Can someone help me please?
    Thanks in advance!

```css
#mailArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px; 
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#mailwebArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px; 
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="choiceMail">
    <input type= "radio" name="mail_type" value="text" onchange="$('#result').hide()" checked > Texte
    <input type="radio" name="mail_type" value="web" onchange="$('#result').show()"> Web
    <div>
        <div id="mailArea"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="result" style="display:none">
        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-md' style='height: 25px; margin-top: 2px; text-align: center; font-weight: https://jsfiddle.net/t44aqpw0/3/#forkbold; font-size: 12px;' onclick='commande('bold');' title='Mettre votre en gras'>G</button>
        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-md' style='height: 25px; margin-top: 2px; text-align: center; font-style: italic; font-size: 12px;' onclick='commande('italic');' title='Mettre votre texte en italique'>I</button>
        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-md' style='height: 25px; margin-top: 2px; text-align: center; font-style: italic; font-size: 12px;' onclick='commande('underline');' title='Soulignez votre texte'>S</button>       <button class='btn btn-primary btn-md' onclick='taille('+', 'mailArea')' style='height: 25px; width: 30px; padding: 0' title='Augmenter la taille du texte'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>             </button>
        <button class='btn btn-primary btn-md' onclick='taille('-', 'mailArea')' style='height: 25px; width: 30px; padding: 0' title='Diminuer la taille du texte'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span>             </button>
    <div id='mailwebArea' class='form-control animated' contenteditable='true'></div>
    <div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: What do you mean? sorry but I'm french

Comment: @JérômeAthion Did you tried yourself with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried with javascript / jquery

Comment: oh ok thanks for ur answer @Mr.x. Hum not exactly, I'm in a bit of a bind :/

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for ur fast answers guys! it works like I want :) I have another problem concerning focus() on div, can I ask my problem here or I create a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple show/hide of your 'mailArea' div based on radio buttons selections:

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=mail_type]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'text') {
    $('#mailArea').show();
  } else if ($(this).val() == 'web') {
    $('#mailArea').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#mailArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#mailwebArea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choiceMail">
  <input type="radio" name="mail_type" value="text" checked> Texte
  <input type="radio" name="mail_type" value="web"> Web
  <div>
    <div id="mailArea">Mail area container</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Cars" + test).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myRadioGroup">
    
    Texte<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="2"  />
    
    Web<input type="radio" name="cars" value="3" />
    
    <div id="Cars2" class="desc">
        Display
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$('#mailArea').hide()` on `onchange` attribute of `input[type=radio]`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choiceMail">
    <input type= "radio" name="mail_type" value="text" onchange="$('#result').hide();$('#mailArea').show();" checked > Texte
    <input type="radio" name="mail_type" value="web" onchange="$('#result').show();$('#mailArea').hide();"> Web
    <div>
        <div id="mailArea">mailArea</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Track the button onclick event. From there, check if div is currently shown. If yes then hide it. If hidden, then show it.

```
$('#yourButtonId').on('click', function(){

  var divElement = $('#yourDivId');
  var isVisible = divElement.is(':visible');

  if(isVisible == true){
    divElement.hide();
  }
  else {
    divElement.show();
  }

});
```